# Please ID deep green fuzzy-leafed shrub

Tags: identification

I've seen this one several times and I like it, but have no idea what it is called. It grows in northern California. Please advise!

[image: My snapshot of the plant]

Answer (score 1):

One candidate for this might be [Woolly Viburnum](https://www.worldplants.ca/display.php?id=5942). Clearly it is a woody shrub, opposite leaf arrangement with recurved leaf and perhaps reminds us of viburnums. Native of China, just a hop skip and jump across the Pacific from California. The rosy colour of the juvenile leaf shoots might be due to unusually dry conditions combined with good amounts of sun.